# How to hide/remove JWPlayer "NEXT IN " popup dialog in android

Tags: android, kotlin, jwplayer

How can I hide/remove this "Next IN 4" (4 is the value of countdown) popup from jwPlayer? Please check the image

I am using jwplayer android sdk version 4. Here is my code for jWplayer

```
val playlistItem = PlaylistItem.Builder()
        .file(episode.intro.toString())
        .image(episode.preview_image)
        .build()
    val playlistItem2 = PlaylistItem.Builder()
        .file(episode.smil.toString())
        .build()

    val playlist: MutableList<PlaylistItem> = ArrayList()
    playlist.add(playlistItem)
    playlist.add(playlistItem2)
    
    val config = PlayerConfig.Builder()
        .playlist(playlist)
        .thumbnailPreview(PlayerConfig.THUMBNAIL_PREVIEW_IMAGE)
        .build()
    jwPlayer.setup(config)
```

[[image]]